# How to install JSON Framework?

Tags: json, frameworks

I have downloaded the JSON Framework from https://github.com/stig/json-framework. Can anyone please post the steps how to install the Framework in Xcode? I have downloaded the Framework i n a Zip file with the name stig-json-framework-5753adb. Please guide me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up some notes some time ago. <del>They're available [here](https://github.com/stig/json-framework#readme)</del>. <del>Now moved [here](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/blob/master/INSTALL.md)</del>. Now moved [here](https://github.com/stig/json-framework#installation).

Comment: Hi Stig, Its great to meet you in this forum. I am a big follower of ur posts. Regarding the installation of JSON Framework, i am little bit confused. I have downloaded it from https://github.com/stig/json-framework and i got the file in Zipped format. When i opened the Zip file i found many folders with different names like " SBJson.xcodeproj, Classes, SBJson, sbjson-ios, sbjson-iosTests, SBJsonTests and Tests" Can u please expalin which folder i need to import into my Xcode to use the JSON Framework. I am also confused about what "Doxygen" mean? Please guide me in installing the Framework...

Comment: It was mentioned in the installation document to run the Doxygen File. Can u please guide me in installing the Framework?

Comment: Read the file I linked to, particularly the information under the *Installation* header.

Comment: @StigBrautaset I have the same issue about installation of your work. The link you post is now not available or 404 not found. Please give me other link for instruction of installing json.